# accessing django form variable in javascript which is inside html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django-forms, django-templates

I have django form with `name` and `email address` as a `form field in forms.py` file.
I am implementing that form in HTML Page with the help of `{form.as_p}`.

Now I have JavaScript inside that same HTML page with...

`{% block javascript %}`

`<script>`

`</script>`

`{% endblock %}`

Now How can I access both form variable inside this `script tag`. I want to validate data at client-side and than wants to send at server.
Will `getElementById()` method works? and If so what I need to write for access my form variables or any other good alternative.
Thanks

Comment: HTML produced by django or by any other means is just HTML

Comment: Thank you for such answers but I am not able to access that's why asked here. Better to help other instead of providing such answers.

Comment: I did not answer your question. I posted a comment. If you want usefull answers, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I already explained the issue briefly, I can't share code. If you can help then thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, its possible. Django gives an id in format `id_fieldname` to each field you define in your Django form.

E.g. For `name` field, id in HTML will be `id_name` and For `email_address` field ,id in HTML will be `id_email_address`

Now you can simply use `getElementById()` in your JS with these ID for validation.

Comment: Hi, I already tried this, but It always showing me [object HTMLInputElement] instead of value.

Comment: For value of a text field use `document.getElementById("id_name").value`

Comment: Hi, It still blank means null value.

Comment: Have you wrote something in text box before calling above ?

Comment: Yes, I wrote but getting null value only.

Comment: Yes it's simple as I am testing right now.

`{% block javascript %}`
    
`<script>`
         
`var name = document.getElementById('id_name').value;`
         
`console.log(name);`
    
`</script>`

`{% endblock %}`

Comment: This code will execute only when your page loads first time. create a function in your JS code and call this on onclick event of submit button of your form for validation `{% block javascript %} 
<script>
function validate() {
    var name = document.getElementById('id_name').value; 
    console.log(name); 
}
 </script> 
{% endblock %} `